# Laravel. always returns 'this action is unauthorized' on model instances

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, model

I am currently experiencing an error with model instances in my routes file. this is after we made a package of our laravel application. It might have something to do with that it cant find the model. But im not sure of that.

```
$router->get('{ticket}', JOIJ\Support\Http\Controllers\Api\Ticket\Show::class)->can('ticketShow', 'ticket'); //does not work
$router->post('', JOIJ\Support\Http\Controllers\Api\Ticket\Store::class)->can('ticketStore', Ticket::class); // does work
$router->patch('{ticket}', JOIJ\Support\Http\Controllers\Api\Ticket\Update::class)->can('ticketUpdate', 'ticket'); // does not work
```

I do use the model instance in the controller like this(Ticket $ticket) so that should not be the issue.

Comment: Can you post the `TicketPolicy`?

Answer (score 0):

Policy

```
    public function ticketShow(User $user, Ticket $ticket): Response
    {
        if ($user->hasPermission($this->getPermissionId(Permissions::TICKET_SHOW))
            || $user->id === $ticket->user_id
        ) {
            return Response::allow();
        } else {
            Log::warning(
                sprintf(
                    'User %s does not have permission to get this ticket. Ticket: %s',
                    $user->id,
                    $ticket->uuid
                )
            );
            return Response::deny('You are not allowed to see this ticket');
        }
    }
```

Policy binding

```
    protected $policies = [
        TicketReply::class => TicketReplyPolicy::class,
        Ticket::class => TicketPolicy::class,
        Note::class => NotesPolicy::class,
        \App\Models\User::class => UserPolicy::class,
    ];
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).